# ruby on rails error while starting mongrel :: no such file to load -- svn/core (MissingSourceFile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

I am using rails 2.3.8 ...i have the following gems installed

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (3.2.8, 2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.18, 2.3.8)
ar-extensions (0.9.5)
arel (3.0.2)
athlite-actionwebservice (2.3.8)
aws-s3 (0.6.2)
aws-ses (0.4.4)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.3.5)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
cmdparse (2.0.2)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
columnize (0.3.1)
daemons (1.1.0)
dbi (0.4.5)
deprecated (2.0.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.0.2, 1.4.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (0.6.3)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
gmail (0.4.0)
gmail_xoauth (0.4.1)
hike (1.2.1)
hpricot (0.8.6)
httparty (0.8.3)
httpclient (2.3.4.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.3)
json (1.8.1, 1.7.3)
linecache (0.43)
mail (2.4.4)
memcached (1.7.0)
mime (0.1)
mime-types (1.19)
mongrel (1.1.5)
mongrel_cluster (1.0.5)
multi_json (1.3.6)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
nokogiri (1.5.5)
oauth (0.4.7)
open4 (1.3.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1, 1.1.6)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (2.3.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.2.2)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdoc (3.12)
ref (1.0.5)
rmagick (2.13.2)
ruby-debug (0.10.3)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.3)
rubygems-update (1.3.7)
sass (3.1.20)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
soap4r (1.5.8)
sprockets (2.1.3)
svn_wc (0.0.6)
thor (0.15.4)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.7)
will_paginate (2.3.14)
xml-simple (1.1.2, 1.1.1)
```

but while restarting the mongrel server i am getting the following error in logs

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- svn/core (MissingSourceFile)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/svn_wc-0.0.6/lib/svn_wc.rb:20
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /usr/local/sokrati/.deployments/tasteIt.11132013143834/tasteIt/app/models/chuknu/svnHandler.rb:3
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /usr/local/sokrati/.deployments/tasteIt.11132013143834/tasteIt/app/models/chuknu/generatorScript.rb:5
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_on'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in `require_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:414:in `load_application_classes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `load_application_classes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:411:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:411:in `load_application_classes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:197:in `process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /usr/local/sokrati/tasteIt/config/environment.rb:17
```

i have svn_wc installed
what is the exact cause of this?
I am new to RoR ..en elaborate answer would certainly help!

Answer (score 0):

To cite from the [Readme](https://github.com/dvwright/svn_wc/blob/master/README.rdoc#requirements) of the svn_wc gem:

> Requires that the Subversion (SWIG) Ruby Bindings are installed.
>
> (which could be as easy as)
>
> - Linux
>
>   - Redhat and Fedora: `yum install subversion-ruby`
>   - Ubuntu and Debian: `apt-get install libsvn-ruby`
> - OS X
>
>   - `sudo port install subversion-rubybindings`
> - Windows
>
>   - unknown,...

Thus, you need to install the ruby bindings for your subversion clients first. They are not part of the gem and are shipped with subversion. Depending on how you installed your Ruby, it might thus be very easy (see above) or rather difficult to obtain the correct bindings (when using rbenv or rvm).

Comment: Any hope for windows users ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess SVN library of ruby is not installed. Just try:

```
apt get install libsvn-ruby
```

it works most of the time.

if it doesnt work, I guess you have to follow what Holger just mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed these problem with this:

> sudo apt-get install libsvn-ruby